# Locating an equivalent clamp

Tags: mechanical-engineering, threads

I am looking to locate an equivalent part similar to the one pictured below which I came across. I think it must be a bespoke piece for this particular item. It is essentially a saddle clamp which has a female connection for an m8 bolt.

[image]

Comment: Find one similar, then drill and tap for M8.

Comment: that looks like a clamp for tapping into a water pipe for a refrigerator water line